# WIX Bootstrapper uninstall without uninstalling MSI how to?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.11

I'm building a WIX Bundle/Chain bootstrapper. It runs and installs like I specified.
I would like to be able to uninstall the bootstrapper without installing the installed MSI. How to accomplish that?
I'm using WIX 3.11.
Other posting here seem to have the opposite behaviour and demand. They seem to use other versions of wix (<=3.10).
Is there a way to accomplish that behaviour?
Some snippets:
    
...

```
</Chain>
```

TK

Comment: Can you give some more details around why you want to do this and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to install some Windows updates in the bootstrapper but I don't want the bootstrapper to appear in the Programs control. I know that I can make it invisible but that is only the second best solution as it can still be uninstalled with the bootstrapper itself and that would uninstall the application MSI.

Answer (score 0):

In your MsiPackage node, add the Permanent flag and set it to yes.  When you uninstall your bootstrapper, the msi(s) set this way will remain installed on the machine.

```
<MsiPackage Id="MSI2KEEP"
Cache="no"
Compressed="yes"
Name="MSI2KEEP"
ForcePerMachine="yes"
DisplayInternalUI="no"
Vital="yes"
**Permanent="yes"**
SourceFile="$(var.MSI2KEEP.TargetPath)"
DisplayName="MSI 2 KEEP"
Description="MSI 2 KEEP" />
```